# LoadPicture error invalid picture

Tags: vba, powerpoint, loadimage

I am trying to take an image from a folder to check its width after that. To do it I am using the following peace of code:

```
         Dim pic As IPictureDisp
         Dim var As Variant
         var = "C:\Myfolder\Animage" & animationNum + 1 & ".png"
         pic = LoadPicture(var)
```

It is giving me "invalid picture" error. I tried also just using the following line:

```
        width = LoadPicture("C:\Myfolder\Animage" & animationNum + 1 & ".png").width
```

But it also gave me the same error. How can I load the picture?

**EDIT**

I try with a jpg image and it works... Does this function some issues with png files?

Comment: are these actually valid picture paths?

Comment: yes they are... I check if the picture was there and it was there so I don't think that is the path problem. Actually I tried with another path (from another picture) and I get the same error.

Comment: I suspect that LoadPicture accepts BMP, JPG and maybe GIF but not PNG (that's the case for LoadPicture used with image controls on forms).

Comment: LoadPicture doesn't know about PNG, because it's such a modern file format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264946%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> Graphics formats recognized by Visual Basic include bitmap (.bmp)
>   files, icon (.ico) files, cursor (.cur) files, run-length encoded
>   (.rle) files, metafile (.wmf) files, enhanced metafiles (.emf), GIF
>   (.gif) files, and JPEG (.jpg) files.

**.png** is not supported.

Comment: It is not a solution but at least I have an explanation of why is not working... thanks!

Comment: I found a workarround in chapter 8 of [RibbonX](http://www.wiley.com/go/ribbonx). It recommends using Window's GDI+ API to load the PNG. There should be some helpful code in the download files for the book. The explination in the book begins on page 274.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, on Windows 10 Office 365.

In my case, the jpeg file I needed to add to a user form had been sent to me via Microsoft teams, and windows security had automatically blocked it.

I had to check the `unblock` checkbox in the attached image, and was then able to add it to a userform.[image]

Answer (score 0):

LoadPicture command does not seem to like filenames greater than 35 characters in length when operating in later versions of Office. I can load a picture to a userform in Windows 7 Office 2010 and it seems to handle any length of filename, but once you move to Windows 10 / Office 2013 onwards if you go over the 35 character length the Err.Description simply says: "Path/Access error".

Limit your filename to 35 chars and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for this exact issue and found a solution on another site, so I thought I would share it here.

I did not come up with this code, it is from Experts Exchange here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_26980514.html

If you import the `.bas` file you can use `LoadPictureGDI()` in place of `LoadPicture()` which converts the picture prior to loading it into your userform or sheet.